# Dublin-Newark-Vancouver. Two-hour layover

Tags: usa, air-travel, luggage, layovers, ewr

In a couple of weeks I am traveling from Dublin to Vancouver, with a layover in Newark. I am flying first with Aer Lingus then Air Canada. I have a two hour layover and am wondering if that's enough time. Also, will my bags will be checked through or will I have to do do that?

Thanks

Comment: Are both legs on a single ticket?

Comment: yeah they are, i bought them through travel republic

Answer (score 4):

You will preclear US immigration and customs in Dublin, and your bags should be checked through, so all you have to do in Newark is walk from one plane to the other. Two hours should be plenty of time if your first flight is not delayed.

Answer (score 3):

Newark airport has [many separate gate areas behind security](http://www.travelnerd.com/airports/newark-airport-EWR/terminal-map). Depending which ones you're using, you *may* be able to take the [United Airlines transfer shuttle](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/airport/maps/ewr.aspx) to avoid leaving security.  Otherwise, you may have to leave security to transfer from one to another.

The [Newark Airport airlines list](https://www.airport-ewr.com/newark-airlines.php) shows Aer Lingus at Terminal B and Air Canada at Terminal A.  Fortunately, as ajd said, you'll [preclear US immigration and customs in Dublin](https://www.dublinairport.com/at-the-airport/passenger-information/us-preclearance-facility).  So even if the transfer shuttle isn't an option, 2 hours would be enough to leave security in Terminal B, take the AirTrain to Terminal A, and clear security for the next flight.